# Dice Loop, adding together different rolls

Tags: c#, dice

How would I be able to display the score each player throws at the end of each round? (I'm treating 1 round as 1 throw per player)

Incidentally, If a player throws a 6 they roll again.

```
Console.WriteLine("Player 1, enter your name");
PlayerOne = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Player 2, enter your name");
PlayerTwo = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Player 3, enter your name");
PlayerThree = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Player 4, enter your name");
PlayerFour = Console.ReadLine();

Random DiceRandom = new Random();
int DiceThrow = DiceRandom.Next(1, 7);
Console.WriteLine(DiceThrow);
Console.ReadLine();


for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    DiceThrow = DiceRandom.Next(1, 7);
    Console.WriteLine("Player " + i + " rolled a " + DiceThrow);
    Console.ReadLine();
    if (DiceThrow == 6) i--;
}

Console.WriteLine("Player 1 rolled a " + DiceThrow);
Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Player 2 rolled a " + DiceThrow);
Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Player 3 rolled a " + DiceThrow);
Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Player 4 rolled a " + DiceThrow);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: you don't appear to have understood the answers to your previous question on this topic. BTW, not sure I agree with this incremental approach to getting your homework done.

Comment: Why didn't i had homework like this :( only singing, clapping and dancing your name ... Anyway What exactly is a score in your game? The sum of all throws of every player? Well then just do it. You know what variables are, at least i hope a teacher told you, and it shouldn't be to difficult to add the value of each throw to a score variable.

Comment: It's actually not homework as a matter of fact, i'm just new to coding and messing around. Since the answer last time was so helpful i figured i' ask again.

@doforwhile, a score is each players throw in each round added together.  

Say Player 1 throws 2,
 Player 2 throws 3,
Player 3 throws 4,
player 4 throws 5,

their scores would be 2,3,4 and 5. However I want the scores to add together at the end of every round and be displayed.

Comment: @user1890490 Thats what i meant with my comment. Ask yourself, what informations do i need (you already knew that) and when do you know that (when do you have a new throw value), now you need a place to store that and add it to the old value. You know what variables are, and now is propably a good time to learn about [arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Because with arrays this whole thing becomes much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything to hold the values that the players are getting? Something simple such as `player1Score`, `player2Score` etc.

Also an if statement in the for loop that asks 
`(if i==1){player1Score = player1Score + DiceThrow})` etc would do wonders.

Answer (score 0):

well here is a small example of how to do it, a little bit better. Alot of stuff is in there which you propably don't know yet. The reason i give you an answer is to provide you with enough new stuff to check it out by yourself.

```
Random diceRandom = new Random();
var scores = new int[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    do
    {
        var roll = diceRandom.Next(1, 7);
        Console.WriteLine("Player " + (i + 1) + " rolled a " + roll);
        Console.ReadLine();
        if(roll != 6)
            score[i] += roll;
    }while(roll == 6);
}

// results
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Player {0} scored {1}", i, scores[i]));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Just a quick roundup:

- Modifying the loop counter is usually bad practice and should be avoided, so instead i use a nested do/while loop.
- I use arrays to store each players score, in the array itself holds 4 ints, each one for every players score. That makes it very easy and simple to iterate over it.
- The previous point is one of the main reasons that for loops are usually started at 0 not at 1, because the first index in an array is [0] and therefore an array with 4 elements has the indices 0, 1, 2, 3. This is important to remember.
- In the results part i used a method from the String class called `Format` where you can use a complete text and add placeholders, that you want to fill with the value of a variable. {0} is the first parameter, {1} the second and so on.